# Linq query Contains method with where condition with case sensitive less search

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying get the data which is contains single word with in the word.Like below query.

```
List<Models.tbluser> memberslist = new List<Models.tbluser>();
var obct = (from memlist in objcontext.tblusers
           where memlist.logname.Contains(member)
          select new
          {
              userid = memlist.userid,
              logname = memlist.logname,

              decription = memlist.description
           }).ToList();

foreach (var item in obct)
{
    memberslist.Add(new tbluser
        {
            userid = item.userid,
            logname = item.logname,

            description = item.decription
         });
}

return Json(memberslist);
```

But here my problem is i need to search with out case sensitive.

For example

If i search with 'a' i need to get data like Admin,Administrator,User Data.

But i am not getting all these because i am searching with Contains() method.Please let me know how can i get all value either the search value is case sensitive less also.

Comment: I don't see where you are using `Contains` in that code.

Comment: _"i am searching with Contains() method"_ Where?

Comment: Sorry i updated now.

Comment: You are NOT searching using `Contains()` or at least not in the code you have posted. If you want to do a case insensitive `Contains()` equivalent see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change them to **Lower** or **Upper** Case when checking the condition using `ToLower()` or `ToUpper()`:

```
var obct = (from memlist in objcontext.tblusers
            where memlist.logname.ToLower().Contains(member.ToLower())
            select new
                 {
                   userid = memlist.userid,
                   logname = memlist.logname,
                   decription = memlist.description

                 }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Change your where condition to be:

```
memlist.logname.ToUpper().Contains(member.ToUpper())
```

---

As a side note, you can shorten your query a bit (you don't need to create an intermediary list):

```
var memberslist =  objcontext.tblusers
    .Where(x => x.logname.ToUpper().Contains(member.ToUpper())
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x => new tbluser
        {
           userid = x.userid,
           logname = x.logname,
           decription = x.description
        })
    .ToList();

return Json(memberslist);
```

Comment: At least for Linq2SQL you cant create table entities inside a db query. `Explicit construction of entity type '...' in query is not allowed.`

Comment: @Magnus good point, added `AsEnumerable()` to workaround that issue.